# Hyperref mouse over action on links

Tags: hyperref

Using `hyperref` package, is it possible to have links that change their color when you hover over with the mouse similar to the HTML link behavior in browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pdflatex, as far as I know: No

This is not really related to (La)Tex neither to hyperref but more about pdf viewers. In a browser, this behavior is defined in the css style sheet, but pdf viewers dont have such a mechanism.
I've tried a few (Adobe of course, but also Foxit, Edpfview, Evince...), and never saw one that had this behavior.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. There seem to be several ways of achieving this within the pdf specs. Quickly googling around shows methods using pdf forms or javascript. However these methods may only work in Adobe reader. The huge caveat here is whether it is possible to do these things within LaTex. And that I don't know.

Comment: Just checked pdf specs 1.5 that I had locally. Table 8.20 on page 576 says nothing about this. But indeed maybe more recent formats allow this? And I assume that if so, then probably the hyperref package would need some upgrade...

Comment: This is not true see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEyJuT8SSME).